# Tailwinds transition not working on button toggling

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a conditional class for 'show' when show is true our div element should transition in from -right-[55rem]  to right-[0rem] the issue is it is not doing this w/ a duration of 700ms it just pops open, when I do the inspect on dev tools I can click and unclick the style elements and it will slide in like I want it to. I have made sure everything i numerical value on TW side and cannot figure out why it works on inspect and not on the actual button click for our ui

[image]

```
        <div className={classNames(show ? "right-[0px] top-0 transition-all duration-700 ": "top-0", "-right-[330px] mt-14 md:mt-0 w-screen  md:left-0 absolute md:fixed md:w-40 bg-default overflow-y-auto flex")}></div>
```

Comment: oddly enough it works perfectly fine on hover if i leave some of the div visible enough to hover but that's not what our design calls for :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
<div className={`${show ? `right-[0px] top-0 transition-all duration-700`: `top-0`} -right-[330px] mt-14 md:mt-0 w-screen  md:left-0 absolute md:fixed md:w-40 bg-default overflow-y-auto flex`}></div>
```

Comment: nope--- further researching looks like i need the headless ui <Transition> instead

Comment: <Transition
        as={Fragment}  
        appear={true} 
        show={show}
        enter="absolute top-0 transition-all ease-in-out duration-700 transform"
        enterFrom="absolute top-0 -translate-x-full"
        enterTo="absolute top-0 translate-x-0"
        leave="absolute top-0 transition-all ease-in-out duration-700 transform"
        leaveFrom="absolute top-0 translate-x-0"
        leaveTo="absolute top-0 -translate-x-full"></Transition>

this is what i should be using but still get some weird layout shift

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the package released a fix :)

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/pull/1803

serveral failed attempts with headless ui Transition finally got it working with this snippet wrapping my component. perfectly sliding into to view :)

```
    <Transition
    as={Fragment}  
    appear={true} 
    show={show}
    enter="transition-all ease-in duration-500 "
    enterFrom="-right-full"
    enterTo="right-0"
    leave="transition-all ease-out duration-500 "
    leaveFrom="right-0"
    leaveTo="-right-full"
    >
    <div className="absolute top-[56px] md:mt-0 md:left-0 w-screen 
     md:fixed 
     md:w-40 bg-default overflow-y-auto flex">...</div>

    </Transition>
```